# Devo evitar operações entre constantes num loop?

Tags: c++, desempenho, estilo-de-codificação, otimização, constantes

No C++ há alguma espécie de otimização ou cache que evite que a mesma operação matemática entre constantes seja repetida, principalmente em *loops*, diminuindo desta forma a performance do aplicativo?

Por exemplo:

```
for (int i=0; i<=100; i++)
    std::cout << i  << " metros/s:" << " = " << i * (3600 / 1000) << " Km/h" << endl;
```

O exemplo acima obviamente é fictício, mas é só para ilustrar a situação. Poderia ser um *loop* de milhões de vezes com centenas de cálculos envolvendo constantes repetidas.

Então pergunto:

1. O cálculo "(3600 / 1000)" será executado repetidamente durante as 100 vezes do *loop*?
2. Desta forma, para evitar perda de desempenho eu deveria armazenar este cálculo em uma variável constante antes do *loop* e trocar o cálculo por essa variável?
3. Ou eu não preciso me preocupar com isso pois o C++ dá um "jeito" de otimizar essas situações automaticamente para evitar perda de performance?

Entendo que esta dúvida seja pertinente, pois envolve o estilo de programação que deve ser adotado.

Comment: Rogério, isso se chama expressão constante. Compiladores de C++ que identificam a necessidade de operar dois inteiros conhecidos em tempo de compilação normalmente os opera e coloca o resultado no lugar da operação para assim gerar o executável de tal maneira que se ganhe desempenho em execução por redução de instruções executadas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> O cálculo "(3600 / 1000)" será executado repetidamente durante as 100 vezes do loop?

Não há garantias que ocorra, mas na prática será otimizado sim e a operação será resolvida em tempo de compilação não gerando custo na execução.

> Desta forma, para evitar perda de desempenho eu deveria armazenar este cálculo em uma variável constante antes do loop e trocar o cálculo por essa variável?

Não, eu nem chamaria isso de cache, porque implicaria que será resolvido uma vez em tempo de execução, nem isso ocorre. Só seria útil fazer isso na expressão toda se você sabe que uma variável não varia dentro do laço, o que não é o caso do `i`. Mesmo esta otimização pode ser aplicada por algum compilador se couber, mas já deve ser menos comum, e neste caso terá uma operação em tempo de execução e depois o resultado será usado como um cache.